# Does openpyxl preserve cell color?

Tags: openpyxl

I'm creating an Excel file from the template. So I expect the formatting of the template to be preserved. However it seems saving of the workbook to new file looses some of formatting (at least cell color).

Original file looks like that:

[image]

I do then following:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.open('c:\\temp\\test_templ.xlsx')
wb.save('c:\\temp\\test.xlsx')
```

Resulting file is 9KB smaller than original and looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to save the Excel file with keeping the formatting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it does. The problem I have met was abnormally complex Excel file with thousands of styles. So it seems some of them weren't properly read by `openpyxl` and hence the problem I had. But if you start with the clean slate and add necessary formatting `openpyxl` does the job just fine.